# qt4 the clicked signal in the connect button doesn't trigger the settext in the label

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

The app runs okay but the clicked() signal doesn't trigger the setText() of the label. Any hint why it doesn't?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setText("change");

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), label, SLOT(setText("<h1>hello</h1>")));

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    window->setLayout(layout);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments within the connection must indicate the signature between the signal and the slot, that is, they must indicate the types of objects that send the signals and receive the slots. In this case it does not make sense to place `"<h1>hello</h1>"`. A possible solution is to create a class that inherits from QLabel and in that method implement a slot where the text is changed.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>

class Label: public QLabel{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QLabel::QLabel;
public slots:
    void updateText(){
        setText("<h1>hello</h1>");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    Label *label = new Label("hello");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setText("change");

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), label, SLOT(updateText()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    window.setLayout(layout);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In Qt5 and Qt6 it is no longer necessary to implement the classes since a lambda function can be used.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setText("change");

    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, label, [label](){
        label->setText("<h1>hello</h1>");
    });

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    window.setLayout(layout);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```